# Token Replacements

Tags: 7, tokens

What is the proper way to store token replacements in a variable? Or should i even bother and call them directly?

Things like:

```
$author_uid = [node:author:uid];
$name = [node:title];
$picture = [node:field-image-upload:file];
$link = [node:url];
```

Are giving me an error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':'
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Also in regards to this line:

```
$picture = [node:field-image-upload:file];
```

What I'm really trying to get is the url link to that image file. How can I do this with a token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Token are a kind of meta language that needs to be processed to get the proper value. For it, you should send your token into a process function called `token_replace`.

Here is an example :

```
$author_uid = token_replace('[node:author:uid]');
```

Check this [documentation page](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal!includes!token.inc/function/token_replace/7) for further informations

Comment: Note that for hardcoded tokens, this doesn't make much sense, just access the value ($node->uid in this case), directly. token_replace() is useful for configurable strings, like mail subjects/bodies and other kinds of messages that users can configure.