# How to replace a Token in the PHP evaluation of a Rule?

Tags: 7, rules, tokens

I'm trying to grant Userpoints to users with a Rule. The Rule first calculates two integer values 'New value' and 'Old value'. Debugging these numbers shows that there's no problem with them. Naturally, I tried awarding the points with an action "Grant points to a user" and I'm using the following code in the PHP evaluation:

```
if ($value > 5) {
  return 0;
}
else {
  return token_replace('[new-value]');
}
```

where the default `$value` is *old-value*.  As the `[new-value]` token is available in the data selectors of the 'Points' section of the action, I suppose that one can use it in the PHP evaluation too. Therefore, after reading [Token Replacements](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38732/token-replacements?rq=1), I thought my code should work, but it doesn't: the Userpoints aren't granted to the user.

There's definitively something wrong with the Token, because the Rule is executed correctly when I use `1` instead of `token_replace('[new-value]')`.

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what went wrong, but I've solved the problem in an alternative way. Everything works fine when you follow the steps underneath.

1. Save the integers *Old value* and *New value* as variables.
2. Add a third variable *Result*. Thanks to step 1, one can use `$old_value` and `$new_value` in the PHP evalution of this variable. I've used this code:

   ```
   if ($old_value > 5) {
     return 0;
   }
   else {
     return $new_value;
   }
   ```
3. Convert *Value* to an integer *Final value*.
4. Award *Final value* Userpoints to the user of your choice.